# Bootstrap grid align left and right with correct spacing, so new line doesn't happen too early

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get two separate bars of horizontal buttons on one line to work well with different window sizes, though I'm having a bit of trouble getting the behaviour I want.

Basically, a table does do the formatting correctly, in that you can have two cells, set one to align right, and as long as there is enough space for everything on one line, everything is fine.

However, as soon as the width is too small, the buttons group together in the cells. I prefer the bootstrap way of sending them to a new line.

The downside of the bootstrap way though, is it doesn't seem to support dynamic widths, so you'll notice my right aligned things being sent to the bottom before they reach the left aligned things. I'm wanting the best of both worlds, so it'll act like the table but then send to a new line.

Is this possible with bootstrap? I've read that apparently you can't do dynamic widths, though this seems like it should be fairly standard.

[An example here](http://tinyurl.com/nb229hh) (bootstrap at the top, table at the bottom, I did the site in PHP so apologies about the html missing line breaks (if you would like that code to build on, I'll sort it out for you), but you get an idea of what I'm after.

Comment: http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

Comment: Thanks, updated the link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a class in bootstrap

```
.pull-left // which will arrange content in left
```

similarly

```
.pull-right // which will arrange content in right
```

> see here **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/meeneshjain/DTcHh/11019/)**

Comment: Thanks, is all you changed literally just that? It seems to fit so much better. There is one problem though which I've just noticed on mine too, at a certain width which is more than large enough, it'll put the last of the left buttons on a new line. Don't suppose you know a fix for that?

Comment: actually bootstrap has different classes for small large and extra large devices, you need to use all

Comment: Hmm, I think I get you, a class of `.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8` means that it'll go to those sizes once the window reaches the matching size? Edit: yep thanks, didn't realise that, I thought you had to choose whichever size you wanted, removing the `md` bit fixed it.

Comment: yes exactly... bootstrap is easy play with it and you will know much more about it